# SQLAlchemy ORM: Mapping a non-unique column to schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

How would you map a column that is not unique and is not a key into another schema(table)?

```
class TaskEntity(Base, BaseMixin): 
    __tablename__ = "task_entity"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("dag_no", "ordinal_position", name="dag_ordinal_uq_constraint"),)

    task_no = Column(BIGINT(20), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    job_no = Column(BIGINT(20), ForeignKey("job_tb.job_no"), nullable=False)
    task_name = Column(String(128), unique=True, nullable=False)
    ordinal_position = Column(SMALLINT(6), nullable=False, default=1)
```

`ordinal_position` is not unique on its own, but is unique per `task_no` which is unique per `job_no`.

> Ex) `job_no.A` can only have 1 of `task_no.A` which can only have 1 of `ordinal_position.C`. But `job_no.B` can have a `task_no.A` and `ordinal_position.C`.

I am trying to create the below schema in conjunction with `class TaskEntity` above, but am returning a `"errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"` which I am assuing comes from the fact that `ordinal_position` is not unique.

```
class TaskLog(Base, BaseMixin):
    __tablename__ = "task_log"

    task_log_no = Column(BIGINT(20), nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    execution_datetime = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
    start_datetime = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
    duration = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    job_no = Column(BIGINT(20), ForeignKey("job_tb.job_no"), nullable=False)
    task_no = Column(BIGINT(20), ForeignKey("task_entity.task_no"), nullable=False)
    task_name = Column(String(128), ForeignKey("task_entity.task_name"), nullable=False)

    # this is the declaration causing issues:
    task_ordinal_position = Column(SMALLINT(6), ForeignKey("task_entity.ordinal_position"), nullable=False)
```

Have tried using relationships and "primary_join=", but the mapping seems to be very off once the data comes in.

Any inputs, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, then you probably want a `UniqueConstraint` across all three columns:

```
__table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('task_no', 'job_no', 'ordinal_position'),
)
```